# Format numbers like Facebook "likes" - PHP

Tags: php, numbers, format

I need of a function in PHP to format numbers like Facebook "likes".

Example:

12345 = 12,3 K

123456 = 123 K

1234567 = 1,23 M

Thank you!!

Comment: Please read [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Also, understand that SO is for help and not "give me"s or "I need"s

Comment: I know this has been asked here before but having issues finding it.

Comment: something like this? [How to format numbers in php 1,000 to 1k](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703469/how-to-format-numbers-in-php-1-000-to-1k)

Answer (score 4):

Write a function which do this!?

```
function format_num($n) {
    $s = array("K", "M", "G", "T");
    $out = "";
    while ($n >= 1000 && count($s) > 0) {
        $n = $n / 1000.0;
        $out = array_shift($s);
    }
    return round($n, max(0, 3 - strlen((int)$n))) ." $out";
}
```