# How to truncate a number to its highest thousand value with one decimal in PHP?

Tags: php, numbers, rounding, truncated

So I'm wondering what would be the best way to achieve truncate numbers to the highest thousand value in PHP like Facebook, Twitter and else do with their followers counters:

```
echo shortify(5710); // outputs 5.7K
echo shortify(145236); // outputs 145.2K
echo shortify(14365859); // outputs 14.3M
// and so on
```

I don't think PHP has a built-in function that handles this problem so I'm willing to know about any script / Git repo / Symfony bundle that would achieve that goal.

I'm pretty sure this question has been asked on SO but, as english is not my native language, I couldn't find out the right keywords to make a proper research. As such, feel free to flag this question as a duplicate of an already-answered one.

Many thanks.

Comment: Use a logarithm. http://ee1.php.net/manual/en/function.log10.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8549487/1481274