# shorten a long number with php

Tags: php, math, numbers

how can i shorten a long number with php ? So a number like 0.3483748937847832 would become 0.34

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371059/shorten-long-numbers-to-k-m-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please search stackoverflow first - from [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

[`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
return number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483561/689579

or

```
$padded = sprintf('%0.2f', $unpadded); // 520 -> 520.00
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483715/689579

Answer (score 0):

Use round

echo round($number,2);