# Short Number format in PHP Indian Based

Tags: php, function, helper, short

Googled for **Short Number Format in PHP**, got thousands of working results from StackOverflow, Github, etc.. but I didn't get any results for **Indian Format**.

Eg:

In other countries: 1000 is as 1k, **100000** is as **100k**, **10000000** is as **10m**

But in India: 1000 is as 1k OR 1T, **100000** is as **1L**, **10000000** is as **1c**

Can anyone help me to do that?

Comment: Why don't you customise the code and try something and reach us when something doesn't work after you try

Comment: @MehravishTemkar I am getting problem in coding **1c** as Indian format is **00,00,000**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371059/shorten-long-numbers-to-k-m-b/4371114#4371114)

I came up with a solution for you:

```
<?php
function indian_short_number($n) {
    if($n <= 99999){
    $precision = 3;
    if ($n < 1000) {
        // Anything less than a thousand
        $n_format = number_format($n);
    } else {
        // At least a thousand
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000, $precision) . ' K';
    }
/* Use this code if you want to round off your results
$n_format = ceil($n_format / 10) * 10;
if($n >= 1000){ 
$n_format = $n_format . ' K';
}
*/
    return $n_format;   
    }
    else{
    $precision = 2;
    if ($n > 99999 && $n < 9999999) {
        // Anything more than a Lac and less than crore
        $n_format = number_format($n / 100000, $precision) . ' L';
    } elseif ($n > 999999) {
        // At least a crore
        $n_format = number_format($n / 10000000, $precision) . ' C';
    }
/* Use this code if you want to round off your results
$n_format = ceil($n_format / 10) * 10;
if($n >= 10000 && $n < 10000000){ 
$n_format = $n_format . ' L';
}
elseif($n >= 1000000){ 
$n_format = $n_format . ' C';
}
*/
    return $n_format;
}
}
echo indian_short_number(10000);
?>
```

The code for rounding off is not proper. (For `18100` it rounds to `20 K` instead of `19 K`)

I will be thankful if any of the visitors edit the answer with the fixing it.

Hope it helps you.